# Что учитывается в счётчике "99 сообщений ожидают проверки"

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Помню, был вопрос, где говорилось, что счётчик отображает суммарное количество проверок, одинаковое для всех пользователей. Поэтому пользователь в очередях видит меньше вопросов, чем показывает счётчик.

Однако, сейчас у меня во всех очередях 0 проверок за последние сутки, и я определённо не ставил пачку тревог. Однако, счётчик показывает 99, а количество доступных проверок 73+5+0+0+0+0=78.

Чем обусловлена разница в 21 вопрос?

И это точно не кэширование, т. к. я видел изменение счётчика со 101 на 99.

Answer (score 1):

Количество ожидающих сообщений рассчитывается одно для всех, а список доступных у каждого свой.

Разницу между двумя числами составляют проверки:

- инициированные вами,
- где вы нажали "Пропустить" (к этим проверкам можно вернуться, но не через страницу проверок),
- которые уже обработаны вами и ждут обработки другими участниками. Таких у нас довольно много в очереди на закрытие.

Comment: Не только те, где было нажато "пропустить". Разница получается равной количеству проверок, которые уже обработал или инициировал конкретный участник, но которые еще ждут обработки другими участниками.

Comment: @PashaPash, я же написал, что выполненных проверок 0. Пропусков тоже 0. Я не проверял ничего.

Comment: @Qwertiy в очереди на закрытие вопросы висят гораздо дольше, чем сутки. У меня сейчас в очереди на закрытие видно 92 вопроса. Причем некоторые там уже неделю висят - особенно вопросы "покажи код" после того, как автор показал код - закрыть их уже нельзя, нажимать "выглядит нормально" никто не хочет - и они остаются в очереди с 2-3 голосами за закрытие.

Comment: @PashaPash, я ожидал, что их примерно равномерно разгребают. Это ж очередь всё-таки :)

Comment: @Qwertiy но это же **stack**overflow :)

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, забыл о ещё двух категориях. )